# How do I make the camera wider?

Tags: camera

making a project but not all the animation fits on the screen, i don't really want to change the focal lense because it makes it look zoomed out. Instead,[image] i want to just make the camera view wider.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117139/render-dimensions https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201097/how-to-change-the-render-image-size-without-changing-camera-settings https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/how-to-make-a-image-bigger

Comment: The second link that @DuarteFarrajotaRamos will give you a quick and easy answer which does exactly what you want, this one, just in case his comment changes ;)  [How to change the render image size without changing camera settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201097/)